# Access All Files WIthout Prompt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

I'm targeting Android 11. Is there a way to give full access to an application programmatically without having to prompt the User with a dialog, the intent and  ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION etc?

And if not, I would just like to prompt the User one time, not having to prompt the User every time the app runs.

Comment: Are you referring to runtime permissions or something else?
If runtime, the dialog has to be shown every time we require access which is not granted by the user. Note: Users can disable access in device settings at any time they want.

Comment: All permissions you ask at runtime you only have to ask once. Your pre assumption is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a permission in Android you have to ask the user to.
Unless the user disable it, the permission still enabled for your app since the user accepted it.

You can see here how to ask for permissions : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting